# enviar datos con fetch y procesarlos

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, fetch

estoy armando un selector de fechas, el problema es que nose como procesar esta informacion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  boton.onclick = function obtenerDatosSuma(x) {
    var data2 = {
        dia: dia,
        mes: mes,
    };

    fetch("fecha", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ seleccion: data2 }),
    })
        .then(function (data) {
            window.location.href = "/fecha";
            return data.json();
        })
        .then((myJson) => {
            console.log(myJson);
        });
};
```

Error en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Como puedo procesar los datos recibidos con POST?**

Comment: ¿donde quieres pasar esos datos?  ¿a una página nueva llamada /fecha?   ¿por eso haces esto? -> `window.location.href = "/fecha";`

Comment: Pero payload es lo que tu envias, y si la peticion está roja es porque no fue satisfactoria, habría que ver cual es el error que te está botando... Si es problema de la URL, si el proble a es de CORS, si estás mandando algún parámetro incorrecto, etc... que error te sale en la consola?

Comment: @Pipe  cambie las URL y ahora me sale el error en consola. Actualice mi post asi lo puedes ver

Comment: Hay un error en el servidor, debes corregirlo... El servidor te esta retornando un error... Estas esperando que el server te retorne un json, pero tiene un <script> adentro